# Vertically alignment in tabular seems broken

Tags: vertical-alignment, luatex, arrays

Using `m` columns in a tabular, I would expect to get vertically centered cells:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\normalsize
\textbf{Some title}
\newline 
\newline 
\begin{tabular}{m{0.5 cm}>{}m{10 cm}|>{}m{4 cm}@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\hline 
\textbf{1.} & $11 \times \text{?} = 9$ & & \tabularnewline [0.8cm] \hline 
\textbf{2.} & $\text{?} \times \text{?} = 72$ & & \tabularnewline [0.8cm] \hline 

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

with lualatex 1.07 (TeX Live 2018) however, I get:

[image: Tabular with vertically top-aligned cells]

while lualatex 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017) did correctly vertically center the cells.

Is this a bug? Should I correct the tabular formatting? Or is there any workaround for the 1.07 version?

(EDIT: Goal is to get the texts vertically centered like they used to be with lualatex 1.0.4
Software versions:
For the failing TeX Live 2018 / lualatex 1.07:

```
lualatex 2018.7.28
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
array.sty    2018/04/07 v2.4g
```

The previous working TeX Live 2017 / lualatex 1.0.4 has following versions:

```
lualatex 2018.1.13
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
array.sty    2016/10/06 v2.4d
```

)

Comment: I guess this is due to the `[0.8cm]`. What do you try ta achieve, precisely?

Comment: I'd like the texts to be vertically centered. The `[0.8cm]` did not prevent this when using the 1.0.4 version of lualatex.

Comment: with recent `array` this not work as you desired. if you like to have more vertical space in cells, than you should use `cellspace` or `makecell` package and their possibility to add some vertical space above and below cells' contents.

Comment: Which versions of the LaTeX format and of the `array` package do you use, under TeXLive2017/LuaTeX 1.04 and TeXLive2018/LuaTeX 1.07? For what it's worth, I can reproduce the lack of vertical centering on a `MacTeX2018/LuaTeX 1.07/LaTeX2e 2018-04-01 patch level 5/array 2018-04-30 v.2.4h` system, but I can *not* reproduce the issue on a MikTeX 2.9.6600/LuaTeX 1.07/LaTeX2e 2017-04-15/array 2016-10-06 v2.4d` system. Given that both of these sstems use LuaTeX 1.07, I suspect the issue you've come across is related to the LaTeX format and/or to the `array` package.

Comment: @Mico I've added the software versions in my question. Versions of `LuaTex` and `array` both change in my case. Looks like the combination LuaTeX 1.07 and array 2018-04-30 (and later) produces the problem.

Comment: @Zarko thanks, I'll have a look at these packages!

Comment: Sorry, I mixed things up. Now, I fixed it, I hope these informations are the relevant ones. The older version (1.04) does not show a patch level in the format line (it's from a TeX Live 2017 on a FreeBSD box).

Answer (score 3):

lualatex is not relevant here, you see the same output from pdflatex or xelatex.

You are seeing the effect of a bug fix to the `m` column, as you can see by using the old version code with a  `[=2016-10-06]` as below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}[=2016-10-06]

\begin{document}
\normalsize
\textbf{Some title}
\newline 
\newline 
\begin{tabular}{m{0.5 cm}>{}m{10 cm}|>{}m{4 cm}@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\hline 
\textbf{1.} & $11 \times \text{?} = 9$ & & \tabularnewline [0.8cm] \hline 
\textbf{2.} & $\text{?} \times \text{?} = 72$ & & \tabularnewline [0.8cm] \hline 

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: note the new version matches the specification of `[0.8cm]` in the document which was always documented as adding space _after_ the row (or more exactly adding to the default depth of the row)

Comment: So what do you recommend the OP should do, if his/her intent is to achieve vertical centering? Simply load the `array` package with a deliberately chosen older date?

Comment: @Mico possibly set `\arraystretch` rather than use `[..]`  more generally avoid `m` for one-line entries, you really want them all on the same baseline.

Comment: Using `[0.8cm]` was a way to achieve another goal that I thought would not fall into this topic. I have to ask [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449726/81138) for further advice. Not sure which answer I should accept, as one of them explains the reason for the new behaviour and the other one may be a good workaround too.

Comment: as long as the tick doesn't go to @egreg I never mind not getting the tick :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cellspace` package, which lets you define a *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` ((`C` if you load `siunitx`, for compatibility reasons):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{0.6cm}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{0.6cm}

\begin{document}
\normalsize
\textbf{Some title}
\newline
\newline
\begin{tabular}{S{m{0.5 cm}}>{}S{m{10 cm}}|>{}m{4 cm}@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\hline
 \textbf{1.}& $11 \times \text{?} = 9$ & & \\ \hline
\textbf{2.} & $\text{?} \times \text{?} = 72$ & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good and like what I want to achieve. I'll try this as soon as possible. I just do not exactly understand the prefix letter when `siunitx` needs to be loaded too (what will happen in the real documents I use): should I simply replace the `S` by a `C`?

Comment: Yes. The reason for that is that siunitx defines an `S` column type (You may change the prefix as an option on  loading `cellspace`).

Comment: Not sure which answer I should accept, because your answer is giving a possible good workaround and the other is explaining the origin of the problem. Upvoted both. Now, in order to find a workaround that will exactly match my problem required to ask [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449726/81138)...